# WSO2 API Manager Ports

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am having a requirement to publish all APIs developed to run on ports 80 and 443 instead of 8280 and 8243.

I changed the axis2.xml as below and restarted the API Manager server.

```
<parameter name="port" locked="false">80</parameter>
<parameter name="port" locked="false">443</parameter>
```

I can see published APIs in API store showing 80 and 443 ports respectively.
But when I am trying to test it using Postman like below URL, it throws the below error.

URL: http://localhost:80/pizza  & https://localhost:443/pizza

Error: HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Please suggest if there is any configuration missing.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use NGINX for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. If you want to expose your APIs with 80/443, you need to front APIM with a reverse proxy as explained in [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+a+Reverse+Proxy+Server