# Why WSO2 API Manager call the endpoint of a registered HTTPS API using 8243 instead 443? I can't reach my final service

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am finding the following problem with **WSO2 API Manager** (I am working on a WSO2 API Manager 6.2.0 version).

I published an API on the publisher portal. This API expects a **POST** request over **HTTPS** protocol and take a JSON payload as the request body.

The problem is that the published API generates a cURL request like this:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://MY_SERVER:8243/puntualitest/v1.0.0/puntuali" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"header\": { \"msgUid\": \"a36bea3f-6dc6-49d7-9376-XXXXXXX\", \"timestamp\": 1567060509108, \"metadata\": { \"TRACKER_BIZID_REV_CODICE\": \"7175\", \"TRACKER_BIZID_REV_NUMERO\": \"545/2019\" }, \"codApplication\": null, \"codEnte\": null, \"invocationContext\": null, \"caller\": \"SRW\", \"user\": null, \"service\": \"crediti.invioPosizioneCreditoria\" }, \"body\": { \"@dto\": \"binary\", \"content\": \"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj..............+\" }}"
```

The problem is that, as you can see, it is trying to call the final endpoint on the **8243** port instead of on the expected **443** port that is the standard **HTTPS** port.

So this call ends into a **Connection refused** message error because the final endpoint listen on the **443** and not on the *8243*.

So I have some questions:

1. Why WSO2 API Manager try to call the final endpoint on the **8243** and not on the **443** port if the chosen protocol is **HTTPS** that, in theory, works on the **443**?
2. Is there a way to set the final endpoint port that has to be used is  **443**?

Thank you

Comment: How about the suggestion from this people https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497016/wso2-api-manager-ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a production case, your gateways are exposed via a load balancer and it is exposed in the port 443. From lb you can load balance to 8243 gateway servers. You can refer [1] for setting up the load balancer.

If you want, you an change the ports 8280 and 8243. For that you can change those in axis2.xml file which resides in repository/conf/axis2 location.

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
        <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
    </transportReceiver>
```

In the port value, you can change this to 80 and a similar definition can be found for https for the port 8243.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer#ConfiguringtheProxyServerandtheLoadBalancer-Step2-Configuretheloadbalancer/reverseproxyserver

Comment: I think you always have to use sudo to start the server if your want to change the posts to 80 and 443.