# Expose API through 443 WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am currently using WSO2-IS and WSO2-APIM and have created a working api similar to `https://<wso2_host>:8244/api/v1/apipath` I was wondering if it was possible to expose this API through port 443 rather than 8244 ?

Comment: Refer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497016/wso2-api-manager-ports

Comment: I saw that it needs nginx.Is there away do do this with the existing tomcat server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why WSO2 API Manager call the endpoint of a registered HTTPS API using 8243 instead 443? I can't reach my final service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443808/why-wso2-api-manager-call-the-endpoint-of-a-registered-https-api-using-8243-inst)